# How to interpret regression with logs and Interaction (dummy and continous)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation

I have a regression of $Y= a\log(x) +b\log(y) + c\log(w) + dZ + e\log(x)\cdot Z + f\log(y)\cdot Z + g\log(w)\cdot Z$

$Z$ is a dummy while $x,y,w$ are all continuous. How would I interpret the interaction coefficients in this regression?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all note that the regression is equivalent to the one below:

$Y = \begin{cases} a\log(x) + b\log(y) + c\log(w) & \text{for} \;\; Z = 0 \\
d + (a+e)\log(x) + (b+f)\log(y) + (c+g)\log(w) & \text{for} \;\; Z=1 \end{cases}$

It's just a neat way of writing two regressions for two cases of categorical variable $Z$.

Then, you have a level-log model, hence the interpretation of the coefficient should be something along the line: "If we increase $x$ by one percent,
we expect $Y$ to increase by $\frac{a}{100}$ units of $Y$ for the case when $Z=0$ and by $\frac{a+e}{100}$ for $Z=1$."

Comment: Thanks! so would "e" be the effect of a one percent increase in x along with z=1?

Comment: Guess you could describe it as: $\frac{e}{100}$ is just an "extra" effect of a one percent increase in $x$ when $z=1$ compared to $z=0$. But the most common interpretation I know is the one I gave you in the original answer.

Comment: So if "z" represented a policy change, e/100 would be the effect of such change along with an increase in x?

Comment: Yes, you’re correct. You can also try to think about it in terms of Difference-in-Differences (DiD) depending on your background and purpose of the study.